# django 3 - import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() - Runtime Error

Tags: django, ipdb

Just installed django-3.0, I'm used to insert ipdb to stop runtime and inspect functions.
With previous version it was working fine.
Is there any way to get it work?

```
> /home/tec1/workspace/static_site/stagen/hmi/views.py(11)dispatch()
     10     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
---> 11         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
     12 

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 15:52:07] "GET /pg/blog/g/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 695, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tec1/workspace/static_site/stagen/hmi/views.py", line 11, in dispatch
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 92, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 151, in dispatch_return
    self.user_return(frame, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 291, in user_return
    self.interaction(frame, None)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 294, in interaction
    OldPdb.interaction(self, frame, traceback)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdb.py", line 231, in interaction

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 319, in _cmdloop
    self.cmdloop()
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/debugger.py", line 97, in cmdloop
    line = self.pt_app.prompt() # reset_current_buffer=True)
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/prompt.py", line 986, in prompt
    return self.app.run()
  File "/home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/static_site-l8CYf1lN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/application/application.py", line 788, in run
    return get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.run_async(pre_run=pre_run))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 15:52:07] "GET /pg/blog/g/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 15:52:07] "GET /pg/blog/g/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Same problem here. It only happens when `ipdb` statement is inserted

Comment: SAME. looks like ipdb is broken in django 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. If you are using Python 3.7 (which it looks like you do, based on your trace) You can use the new Python breakpoint() instead.

Basically, you would replace

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

By

```
breakpoint()
```

Check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/ There you can find out how to set up more fancy breakpoints as well.